# Is it possible to get only user info with Discord websocket?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, discord

I'm making a discord onliner and after a while I get an error like this

[Imgur Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eby50.png)

I think this is because of the large amount of data coming from the discord websocket, there is really a lot of unnecessary data in the READY event and is there a way to prevent this incoming data from coming or could it be caused by something else?

I tried try catch, it didn't work, I added .catch in another way, I couldn't save it again, all I want is to get rid of this error, but I couldn't :(

Comment: No, you definitely need the ready event, as it provides crucial info needed to continue using the gateway API! This is probably caused by the heartbeat not being returned, which is needed to verify you're still there (or discord disconnects). The gateway is often quite confusing, and you've only vaguely mentioned what you actually need in the title. It might be worth using the HTTP Rest API instead?

Comment: @LarryTLlama No, i return heartbeat event, i am trying to make tokens online, rest api just returns user information :/

Comment: Make tokens online? Are you trying to make a discord bot and trying to login with a token? If so, I think you're making the wrong API calls.